# C# WebSocket message callbacks

Tags: c#, socket.io

I'm coming from the world of `NodeJS` and `Angular`. I used the WebSocket library `Socket.io` there I could use the `ack` `socket.send([…args][, ack])` as a callback function to get direct response.

**What I would like to know is a way to implement a callback in a similar way or another callback protocol that I can use in C#.**

for example:

```
- the client sends an action to be executed in a service (C#) threw socket message.
- the service then executes the action and after X seconds has a response.
- The response should return to the same place where the client sent the request.
```

this is similar to API protocol and that's why the callback function is so handy for me.
I can not use API protocol in this project.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend use [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-3.1) developed by Microsoft however it's native and super simple rather integrate Socket.io

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found [this](https://github.com/doghappy/socket.io-client-csharp) NuGet that works amazing. especially the `Emit with Ack` section.